# A simple question about extreme values of a multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x^2+xy$. Determine all extreme points and characterize them as  maxima or minima.

I computed the relative partial derivatives of the function as $f_{x}=2x+y$, $f_y=x$  $f_{xx}=2$, $f_{yy}=0$, $f_{xy}=1$. I know that If $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2 <0$ at the points $(a,b)$ then the point is considered a saddle point, and that $f_x(0,0)=0, f_y(0,0)=0. $ So considering the second partial derivatives are both constants then the point $(0,0)$ is the only interesting point and it's the saddle point which means the function has no maxima or minima. Is this reasoning correct or is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the reasoning is correct. But, in order to prove that $f$ has no maximum and no minimum, you could simply say that it has no maximum because $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,0)=\infty$ and that it has no minimum because $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(-1,x)=-\infty$.

Comment: That does not exclude local extrema.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed. I have edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I understand the question as a request to characterize all (local) extremal points as (local) maximum or minimum, and the limits do not help to answer that. But I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @MartinR I wrote “the reasoning is correct”. What I meant by this was that the way the OP proved that the origin is a critical point which turns out to be a saddle point was correct, and that the OP was also correct when they deduced from that that $f$ has no maximum and no minimum. I just added that proving this last assertion could be done in a simpler way.